# UITableView with unknown height web image

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstextattachment

I use UITextView to Show NSAttributesStr in tableViewCell , the NSAttributesStr contains some imgs whitch height is unknown, so when I use NStextAttachment to replace The img, I can not set bound.height for NStextAttachment, I must require imgs from net and update the NStextAttachment.bound , and then update the tableViewCell.
The display is very bad and is not smooth. 
Is there a solution? please!

Comment: How do you set the attributedString? You can iterate through the attributedString looking for NSTextAttachment and change the bounds, then set that attributed string to your textView.